# ASP.net MCV - how to convert datetime to string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, sql-server-2012

I want to show date in a FORM, but when i running in browser i get this value

```
/Date(1087789832000)/
```

in my model I make the datatype of the date is:

```
public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
```

in database I use SQLServer , Datatype is DateTime Too.

i already trying to use convert it in My controller like this, but it's not work :

```
DueDate = item.DueDate.HasValue ? item.DueDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : "",
```

and i get error :

```
Cannot implicity convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'
```

anybody can help me to how fix this ?? i want convert it in MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: Either on the client as per the dupe, or you need to add a `string` property to you model and assign the `.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` value to it

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes, i have already trying like you mean, but i've got another error in my query, 
this my query , do you think there is mistake from my query ?
    
**string query = "SELECT A.TtsId, A.InstrumentCode, B.InstrumentFName, B.ISINCode, B.SubTypeCode, A.DueDate, A.ExDate, A.BksClsDate, A.DeclDate, A.DivType, A.Dividend, A.TaxRate, A.Ratio  FROM TTransSchedule As A INNER JOIN TInstrument As B ON A.InstrumentCode = B.InstrumentCode WHERE (A.InstrumentCode = '" + instrumentCode + "') AND (A.TtsId = '" + ttsId + "') ";**

Comment: That's a completely different question, so ask a new question (including the detail of the error)

Comment: String value = DueDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");